# How can I print text using any one of the 256 colors that the terminal allows?

Tags: terminal, colors

I would like to write a program that utilizes all 256 of the Linux terminal's text colors.  To date, however, I have only found a handful of color codes, which are in the format "\033[1;NUMmNUM\033[1;m".  However, these escape codes only allow for two or three dozen colors, *not* the 256 that the Linux terminal supposedly allows for.  How can I display those other colors in my `curses` application?

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look into `TERM` settings. It is possible it is set to lesser then *capable* string. To test colors you can run GNU's [`msgcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/msgcat). Try e.g.:

```
echo $TERM
msgcat --color=test
TERM=xterm-256color
msgcat --color=test
```

Or use [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9785/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)'s loop instead of msgcat.

For more information on *how* and what to set have a look at e.g.:

- [256 colour terminals](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/256-colour-terminals/)
- [TERM strings](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/term-strings/)
- [TTY with 256 colors?](https://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors)
- … etc.

Answer (score 6):

Stop using escape codes and use the `setaf` terminfo capability instead.

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 $(tput colors) ) ; do tput setaf $i ; echo -n "█" ; done ; tput setaf 15 ; echo
```

Comment: I only get eight colors that way, though, and the terminal supposedly supports 256.  Where did all of the other colors go?

Comment: Your terminal only supports 8 colors then. Try another terminal.

Comment: I have tried LXTerm, Xterm, and the Linux terminal (both with and without tmux), and gotten the same result on all three.  Are you sure that the Linux ttys themselves do not support 256 colors?

Comment: `tput colors` on my console resulted in `8`. So I would say that this is not unique to you.

Answer (score 1):

`TERM` tells `tput` (and other applications that use the terminal database) how many colors your terminal (supposedly) supports and how to set the foreground (`setaf`) and background (`setab`) for that.

The example script is close, but doesn't reset properly:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $(tput colors) ) ; do tput setaf $i ; echo -n "█" ; done ; echo ; tput op
```

Here is a screenshot from xterm to illustrate:

[image: example of tput and 256colors]

For what it's worth, `msgcat` uses the terminal database, but then follows up with some hardcoded assumptions about the terminal's color capability.  Some of that needs rethinking, e.g., noticing a coding error for instance in [this line](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gettext.git/tree/gnulib-local/lib/term-ostream.oo.c#n1880):

```
               (strlen (term) >= 4 && memcmp (term, "rxvt", 7) == 0)
```